# I think I found an error on the freecodecamp.com certification

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I'm doing the freecodecamp.com certification and I found what I think may be an error on their side. This part of the HTML module teaches about radio buttons and asks you to add some to the app you code throughout the course. The problem happens when I compile it and the built-in compiler shows the following error:

```
// running tests
Each of your radio button elements should be added within the form tag.
// tests completed
```

And this is my code:

```
<form action="https://www.freecatphotoapp.com/submit-cat-photo">
  <input type="text" placeholder="cat photo URL" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit<button>
  <label for="indoor"> 
      <input id="indoor" type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor">Indoor 
  </label>
  <label for="outdoor"> 
    <input id="outdoor" type="radio"  name="indoor-outdoor">Outdoor 
  </label>
</form>
```

As far as I'm concerned, the code for the buttons is within the `<form>` tags. I tried adding extra `<form>` tags wrapping the whole piece of code and also putting it on another separated `<form>` tag but the error remains unchanged.

I came to ask here first, because even though I haven't found the solution, I'm aware the it's most likely caused by bad, rookie code.

Comment: Your radio buttons have no value property

Comment: I don't understand it. They have their "indoor" and "outdoor" values. Look:
``<label for="indoor"> 
      <input id="indoor" type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor">Indoor 
  </label>``